# What is a 3-cell? What is a 3-disk?

Tags: geometry, knot-theory, cw-complexes, spheres

Checking the usual places on the Web doesn’t (right now) yield a short answer to this simple question. I’m worried that I will spend just as long trying not to confuse $n$- with $(n+1)$-cells as I did trying to keep straight [the geometer's sphere versus the topologist's sphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere.html).

Context seems to matter, as there are clearly different kinds of cells like Schubert cells, Jordan cells, cubical cells, cells in CW complexes, cells ⊂ hyperspheres, ... [a knot talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VR0kfD3tAIw) I was watching takes a different attitude to 2-disks and 3-disks than may be permitted elsewhere, etc….

So, for posterity, could someone please correct me if I'm wrong here:

- a 0-cell is like a point
- a 1-cell is isomorphic to a line segment $\sim [0,1]$. Its image may bend depending on the domain of application.
- A graph is made with 0-cells (nodes) and 1-cells (edges). If there were a self-loop in eg a CW-complex then that self-loop could be considered a 1-cell also.
- a 2-cell is isomorphic to a 2-disk $\sim D^2 = S^1 \text{ along with its interior} = \mathrm{closure}\ S^1$, which is like $\sim [0,1]^2$ except that $[0,1]^2$ [squashes all of the curvature into the four corners](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/13.pdf) instead of “evenly distributing” it. A 2-cell can also be thought of as isomorphic to the closure of a triangle or the closure of a 2-simplex (the 2-simplex is the convex hull of $(0,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,0)$). Usually we should probably think of 2-disks as coming with a requirement of [conformality](http://gsl.lab.asu.edu/archive/teichmuller-1.gif) /smoothness unless we're told otherwise.
  [image: homeomorphic to a solid 2-disk]
  [image: solid unit 2-disks]
- a 3-cell is isomorphic to a solid sphere $= \mathrm{closure}\ S^2$, modulo the above
- a 4-cell is isomorphic to a solid 3-sphere $= \mathrm{closure}\ S^3$, modulo the above
- … and so on …

The cells are *not*  to have holes or punctures in them.

[image: punctured disk]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/PuncturedSet_1000.gif))</sub>

---

The  difference between a cell and a disk is not geometric but rather contextual. "Cell" is meant to indicate many pieces which abut each other in some larger space—and "disk" could be a total space or could be a patch from a total space, but we aren't supposed to think of a foamy sea of disks—if we were, we would use the word "cell".

[image: foam]

Comment: The Wolfram page is essentially just wrong. There is no mainstream literature nowadays, and I suspect Coxeter was even a historical irregularity, that says that unit circle in the complex plane is the "2-sphere". $S^n$ is always the n-dimensional sphere, which sits in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yeah, I actually wrote as hover-text to that link that I'm not even sure geometric vs topologist's spheres is even a real dispute. I was confused by that page for years until I started reading more mathematical literature……

Comment: The three mentions of "closure of $S^n$" in the question are wrong.  For example, the circle $S^1$ is a closed subset of the plane; its closure is itself, not the whole disk that it encloses.  Similarly for higher dimensions.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Right; thanks. Do you think "the interior of S¹" makes sense? (meaning what I'm trying to have it mean)

Comment: I would not refer to the interior of $S^1$ to mean the disk's interior.  We usually just define $D^2:=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x^2+y^2\leq 1 \}$, and then the boundary of $D^2$ is $S^1$.

Comment: "Interior" is a technical term, so I wouldn't use it to refer to a set that's not actually the interior of $S^1$.